# Is it correct to omit definite article before the phrase "election day"

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

We'll find out where the chips fall on **election day**.

This sentence can be rewritten as follows:

**The** election will clarify how the local residents feel about it.

**Election day** will clear up all the current uncertainties.

I wonder why there is no definite article before the phrase "election day."

Comment: Do we say "Christmas Day" or "the Christmas Day"? What about other holidays or proper nouns?

Answer (score 2):

Both the speaker and the audience know which "election day" is being talked about.  In context, "Election Day" becomes the name of a day, similar to "Sunday", "Easter", "Thanksgiving", or "Christmas".

Comment: Many thanks for the answer that the phrase should be considered as one of those days like Sunday or Thanksgiving Day. As a non-native speaker of English, it would be helpful if native speakers would write the first letter of the phrase in capital.